# Rigveda verse after nocturnal emission in manusmriti

Tags: rig-veda, manu-smriti

It is mentioned in Manusmriti in the 181th line that "A twice-born student, who has involuntarily wasted his manly strength during sleep, must bathe, worship the sun, and afterwards thrice mutter the Rik-verse (which begins), 'Again let my strength return to me.'"
Which verse is described here?
https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu02.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explanatory notes by Ganganath Jha in his translation of [Manusmṛti (with Medhātithi's Manubhāṣya)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199657.html) say that Manusmṛti 2.181 is referring to Taittirīya Āraṇyaka 1.30 (of Kṛṣṇa Yajurveda):

> 'Punarmām' – "This verse occurs in Taittirīya Āraṇyaka 1.30," – Buhler.
>
> 'Punarmāmaitvindriyam' – "Taittirīya Āraṇyaka 1.30. Such uses of texts are frequent in the later Vedic works; e.g. the Sāmavidhāna Brāhmaṇa and the several Ṛgvidhānas," – Burnell.

From [here](https://archive.org/stream/10TaittiriyaAranyakaAccented2#page/n30/mode/1up), the verse in full:

> [[1-30-1]] 
>   punarmāmaitvindriyam | 
>   punarāyuḥ punarbhagaḥ | 
>   punarbrḥhmaṇamaitu mā | 
>   punardraviṇamaitu mā | 
>   yanme'dya retaḥ pṛthivīmaskān | 
>   yadoṣadhīrapyasaradyadāpaḥ | 
>   idam tatpunarādade | 
>   dīrghāyutvāya varcase | 
>   yanme retaḥ prasicyate | 
>   yanma ājāyate punaḥ | 
>   tena māmamṛtaṃ kuru | 
>   tena suprajasaṃ kuru ||1||
>
> punardve ca ||
>
> iti kṛṣnayajurvedīyataittirīyāranyake 
>   prathamaprapāṭhake triṃśo'nuvākaḥ ||30||

Translation and commentary of the verse(s) from [*Essence of Taittiriya Aranyaka*](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/ESSENCE_OF_TAITTIRIYA_ARANYAKA.pdf) (kamakoti.org):

> 1.30.1-3: May mantra shakti lead to physical fulfillment and good progeny
>
> *Punarmaamaittvindriyam punaraayuh punarbhagaha, 
> punarbraahmanamaitu maa punardravinamaitu maa /* 
>   *Yanme~dya retah prithiveemaskaan yadoshadheerapyasaradyaapaha 
> idamtatpunaraadade
>   deerghaayuttvaaya varchase /* 
>   *Yanme retah prasichyate | yanma aajaayate punaha | tena maamamrutam
>   kuru | tena suprajasankuru /*
>
> ---
>
> This anuvaka deals with human desires and their fulfillment. The prayers are for awakening senses, their strength and intensities. The prayers are to revive and reinforce the world of aspirations and thus the frontiers of life span, the power of enjoyment, their sustenance and enhancement.
>
> May the mantras of prosperity and longevity to enjoy the sweet fruits of life respond instantly. May the "retas" or semen be spilled on earth and enhance the derivatives of plants, progeny and pashus. Besides these again, the long life, the capacity to enjoy and the determination towards fulfillment be heightened further and farther.
>
> Finally, may the semen deposited in the womb of the wife result in many sons with name and fame besides our immortality!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In the question, Manu mentions a richa while this is from Yajurveda. Is this verse something that the Yajurveda borrowed from the Rigveda?

Comment: I couldn't locate such a verse in the [Rigveda samhita](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gret_utf.htm#Samh). Also, apparently, there are about 700 rk mantras in Taittiriya Samhita which are not present in the current Rigveda. So Manu may/may not be referring to Rigveda @user1952500

Comment: @sv i have searched deep into the matter and manu is talking about rigveda but seems the verses are lost.I will search more and let u all know.

Comment: @PravinRGMishra 'but seems the verses are lost' - no, the verses are not lost because the same/similar verses are present in YV. The RV shakas/recensions with those verses however could be lost.